# Listing elements of my table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having doubts in the listing record from a table where I use: JOIN, MAX, GROUP BY

I am using the following query:

```
     SELECT cr.*
       FROM cliche c
 INNER JOIN cliche_revisao cr ON c.cliche_pk = cr.cliche_pk
      WHERE cr.numero = (SELECT MAX(number) FROM cliche_revisao WHERE cliche_pk = 3)
   GROUP BY c.cliche_pk
```

**The problem is, as is a listing of all the elements, would not have to pass the literal value in the subquery.**

I tried this query but it did not work

```
     SELECT cr.*, @cliche:= c.cliche_pk
       FROM cliche c
 INNER JOIN cliche_revisao cr ON c.cliche_pk = cr.cliche_pk
      WHERE cr.numero = (SELECT MAX(numero) FROM cliche_revisao WHERE cliche_pk = @cliche)
   GROUP BY c.cliche_pk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you want to use a correlated subquery:

```
 SELECT cr.*
   FROM cliche c
  INNER JOIN cliche_revisao cr ON c.cliche_pk = cr.cliche_pk
  WHERE cr.numero = (SELECT MAX(number) 
                     FROM cliche_revisao cr2
                     WHERE cr2.cliche_pk = cr.cliche_pk)
```

GROUP BY c.cliche_pk

This will get the row corresponding to the maximum value for each `cliche_pk`.

Comment: That's right, I did not know I could reference in the subquery, thank you ;)